# JTable new column Add not successful

Tags: java, swing, csv, jtable

Below is a part of code I am trying to resolve. 
What I am trying t achieve here is "**To add one more blank column at the end and then filling up cell values row by row for that column**".

Eventhough I can debug, in line **table.setValueAt(finalCell, row, table.getColumnCount()-1);**

Its trying to update cell (1,5) but after that line my row becomes **[Hello, , , , 1]** from **[Lee, Hsien Yang, , , , 1]**.

What I am expecting is **[Lee, Hsien Yang, , , , 1,Hello]**

But here its updating first column rather than new 5th one.

How can I achieve my goal?

```
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file)); 

            List<String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();
            String[][] rowData = myEntries.toArray(new String[0][]);

            String[] columnNames = { "People", "Place", "Organisation", "Event", "Mentions" };

            JTable table=new JTable(rowData, columnNames);

            TableColumn newColumn=new TableColumn();
            table.getColumnModel().addColumn(newColumn);

            Boolean isFirstLine=true;

            for(int row=0;row< table.getRowCount();row++)
            {
                if(isFirstLine)
                {
                    isFirstLine=false;
                    continue;
                }
                String finalCell="";

                for(int col=0;col<table.getColumnCount()-1;col++)
                {
                    finalCell="Hello";
                }
                table.setValueAt(finalCell, row, table.getColumnCount()-1);
            }
```

Comment: Use a `TableModel`...[How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an appropriate `TableModel`

```
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file));

            List<String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();
            String[][] rowData = myEntries.toArray(new String[0][]);

            String[] columnNames = {"People", "Place", "Organisation", "Event", "Mentions"};

            DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);

            tableModel.addColumn(""); // What ever name you want to give it...

            Boolean isFirstLine = true;

            for (int row = 0; row < tableModel.getRowCount(); row++) {
                if (isFirstLine) {
                    isFirstLine = false;
                    continue;
                }
                String finalCell = "";

                for (int col = 0; col < tableModel.getColumnCount() - 1; col++) {
                    finalCell = "Hello";
                }
                tableModel.setValueAt(finalCell, row, tableModel.getColumnCount() - 1);
            }

            JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
```

The `TableModel` is generally responsible for managing the data and is generally the go to place to set these things up.

See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

> Thanks but New column name is coming null

Works fine for me...

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                String[] columnNames = {"People", "Place", "Organisation", "Event", "Mentions"};

                String[][] rowData = new String[][]{
                    {"Lee", "Hsien Yang", "", "", ""}
                };

                DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);

                tableModel.addColumn(""); // What ever name you want to give it...

                Boolean isFirstLine = true;

                for (int row = 0; row < tableModel.getRowCount(); row++) {
                    tableModel.setValueAt("Hello", row, tableModel.getColumnCount() - 1);
                }

                JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

What seems strange is, you're example code;

> [Lee, Hsien Yang, , , , 1]

has 6 columns, but you're only allowing for 5...

```
String[] columnNames = {"People", "Place", "Organisation", "Event", "Mentions"};
```

This will overwrite the data for that column when you call `addColumn`

Comment: That's working, Thanks but New column name is coming null. Can u please guide for it?

Comment: It should be `""` unless you changed it.  Try making it something else `"Happy Column"` and see if that has an affect

Comment: I tried replacing by my Column Name, but still its null.

Comment: Can I point out that your data "appears" to have 6 columns, but you're only allowing for 5

Comment: I am new to JTable, can you please elaborate? Else edit in your answer? So that I can lock this question.